# A hangar that have

Tags: verbs

Saw this sentence written in a [news article in the Wall Street Journal", Americas military falls behind russia china race for melting Arctic"](https://www.wsj.com/articles/americas-military-falls-behind-russia-china-race-for-melting-arctic-2a71dfac) (Healy is the name of a ship):

*The Healy has high-tech communications and a helicopter hangar that **have** military uses, but its focus is earth science, especially geochemistry and climate studies.*

I thought the correct word is *has*, especially since it immediately follows *a helicopter hanger*, but on second thought if *high-tech communications and a helicopter hanger* are considered together, then of course this is more than one object and *have* would make sense. But I'm really confused on this one. If anyone can explicitly clarify this it would be greatly appreciated. Because right now I suppose both could be correct?

Edit:

I just came across this sentence further in the same news article.

*A joint Navy and Coast Guard program to build more armed and modern icebreakers **has** been delayed.*

I'm thinking *have* is appropriate here because of *icebreakers*. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's a bit clumsy, but obviously there *are* two subjects for the verb ***have*** (***high-tech communications*** AND ***helicopter hanger***), so it's written correctly. The same applies to your second example, where ***has*** is correct for the singular noun subject ***program***.

Comment: Remember to **link to the source**.  "in a news article" isn't enough. I've done it for you this time, because the source was easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence, your analysis is correct, i.e. "high-tech communications and a helicopter hangar are considered together" is the plural subject of the verb.

Military use seems normal for high-tech communications. However, it's a bit surprising for a hangar.

If we simplify the second sentence, it gives :

> A [joint Navy and Coast Guard] program has been delayed.

in which case *program* is the singular subject of the verb.

Comment: This is correct.   However, it's important that not all connectives work like "and".  When you use "and" to join a list of subjects, the resulting compound subject is always plural.   However, if you use a different connective, this may not be the case:  "Either Steven or Michael **is** going to the prom with Jane."